# chat logs seen when on my phone (not compay computer)

Tags: privacy, logging

can owners of private internet see chat logs when using my phone but their internet? Is this possible. I work in someone's house who is an IT genius and just wondered if they can read my hangout or anything else as they seem to react to stuff I say on chat to people?!

Comment: Reading hangouts - no, seeing overall activity, including whatever you are using hangout - yes.

Comment: Semi-related: Tags `privacy` and `historical` ... yes, you recognized the problem. Now the solution: Stop using Hangouts.

Comment: What you write over Hangout, maybe not (don't know how good Hangout do Certificate Pinning) but other Messenger, yhea he could do. Can he se that you use Hangout? Yes he can.

Answer (score 1):

Hangout uses HTTPS to send and receive messages.

So normal sniffing of data packets of the wire is impossible. Which leaves the possibility of SSL stripping. But this is possible only if you have willingly allowed your employer to do so.

You can check the following.

1. Open `WiFi settings`. Tap and hold your office wifi connection. Tap `Modify`. Check `Advanced Options` and verify whether the proxy is set to `none`.
2. Open `Settings > Security`. Go to `Trusted Credentials`. Verify if any certificate is installed in the `User` tab.

If proxy is set to `none` and no trusted credentials from user is added, no one can sniff https traffic. [Unless you install some malware on your phone and let them do that]

Comment: For future reference: these instructions appear to be for Android ~6.0?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways your connection can be MitMed even while using your own trusted LAN - for instance, see [Room 641A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Room_641A), where the NSA was slurping up a major portion of U.S. internet traffic.

The answer is:  it depends, primarily on the app and how secure the developers have made it.

One of the most important properties that a good encryption system will provide is **confidentiality**, that is, that an eavesdropper cannot ascertain the content of the message.  If the app you're using uses a secure encryption system, like [TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security), then the specifics of what you're sending and receiving are reasonably well protected (modulo any vulnerabilities that weaken the system).

Another important aspect is *metadata* - you're probably making unencrypted DNS requests, which makes it easy to see that you're using Hangouts (or whatever).

> just wondered if they can read my hangout or anything else as they seem to react to stuff I say on chat to people?!

In all likelihood, this is not a technology attack.  It's much more likely they are reading over your shoulder, talking to other people, or are just better at reading you than you think (common examples include teenagers and their parents, and anyone ever trying to hide a romantic relationship).